# Macro to rearrange data

Tags: vba, excel

In the picture ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVuc3.png ) I am given data as seen in columns A-C and need to pull specified portions and display them as seen in columns E and F. In this example the Fund ABC's values from the various Investments listed in columns E and F.

Can someone help me with a macro that would 
(1) prompt user for Fund of interest
(2) pull values of given Fund from the various Investments and line them up next to the name of the investment as seen in columns E and F.

I have posted this in other forums but no response yet.
Ozgrid http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=198481

Steve

Comment: That link is from 2010 and your question was answered?! Also if you have some code and have tried anything you should share it.

Answer (score 0):

INdex/Match should work wonders for you. It's easier than a macro and can be done in sheet

```
 {=INDEX('range where the return value is', MATCH('value needing found', 'range where to look',0))}
```

Remember to enter it with control+shift+enter